# Execute event Paint of picturebox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

In a form I have a picturebox and Rectangle structure,

```
Dim RcDraw As Rectangle
```

I fill the x and y property of this structure

```
RcDraw.X = 10    
RcDraw.Y = 10
```

and I need to execute the paint event of the picturebox in order to see the rectangle in the picturebox, how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Invalidate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.invalidate.aspx) of the `PictureBox`, you also need to assign the `Height` and `Width` to your rectangle

```
PictureBox1.Invalidate()
```

Then in your `Picturebox's Paint EventHandler` you would do something like this.

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, RcDraw)
```

or if you want it filled.

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, RcDraw)
```